# Eloquent with multiple relations

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and ORMs in general, so this is probably a very basic concept that I'm missing.  I have three tables that I'm trying to define a relation with using Laravel 4's Eloquent ORM.  Here's the slimmed-down table definitions:

**stores**
id (PK)
name

**postal_codes**
id (PK)
postal_code
city
state
country

**locations**
id (PK)
store_id (FK => stores.id)
postal_code_id (FK => postal_codes.id)
**additional location-specific fields such as address, phone #, etc*

The `stores` table has a one to many relationship with the `locations` table, so I can use `$this->hasMany("Location")` in the Stores model, and `$this->belongsTo("Store")` in the Location model.

My question is, how do I define the relation between `locations` and `postal_codes` in their respective models?  The `locations` table has a many-to-one relationship with the `postal_codes` table.  Ideally I want to be able to do something like this: `$store->locations()->first()->city`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you looking for something like:

```
class Locations 
{
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('PostalCode');
    }
}
```

So now you can call `$store->locations()->first()->city`. This will return a PostalCode model, if you want to return just the city:

```
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city()->city;
}
```

And then you call `$store->locations()->first()->getCity()`.

You could go further and create a __get() magic method so it calls everything dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the proper way to handle it. I don't know why I made it more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a many-to-many relationship between `Stores` and `Postal_Codes`.  This would be demonstrated this way in Laravel:

```
class Store extends Eloquent {
    public function postal_codes() {
        $this->belongsToMany('Postal_Code', 'location');
    }        
}

class Postal_Code extends Eloquent {
    public function stores() {
        $this->belongsToMany('Store', 'location');
    }        
}
```

For more info, try this link: [Laravel Many-to-Many Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many).

Comment: I think this is correct, but my pivot table (what I've called "locations") has a few other fields besides the foreign keys.  I looked through the docs but didn't see how I'd go about handling this.

Comment: Check this out bro: [Laravel Docs: Working with Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

Comment: Actually, I think what he needs is a polymorphic relation.  I would change the locations table to include id, imageable_id, imageable_type, and then the rest of misc fields for that table.  Check out in that same documentation that searsaw links, the portion on polymorphic relations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a polymorphic relation.

Modify your locations table to include `id`, `imageable_id`, `imageable_type`, and then whatever additional location information you need.  The `imageable_id` field will contain the ID of whatever you are looking for in it's respective table and the `imageable_type` will be whatever the name of that model for that table is.

On your models...

```
Class Location extends Eloquent
{
    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

Class Store extends Eloquent
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Location','imageable');
    }
}

Class PostalCode extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'postal_codes';
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Location','imageable');
    }
}
```

And now, it's possible to retrieve all of the locations for the stores or postal codes with something like

```
$store = Store::find(1);
foreach($store->locations as $location)
{
    //
    echo $location->city;
}

$postalCode = PostalCode::find(1);
foreach($postalCode->locations as $location)
{
    //
    echo $location->city;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's polymorphic because a location does not have a single association with a zip code or a store.  It is associated with a store and a zip code.  Polymorphic relationships are when two different models are associated with another model.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense.  I assumed stores and postal codes were not related, but both had locations.  If it's not possible to just have one table of location information with city, state, country, address, postal code, phone no. etc and make it extremely easy, I believe Aladin has what you are looking for.